# Is there a way to deploy Phonegap Build apps to remote iOS without approval

Tags: ios, cordova

I've developed a phonegap app and have it working and deployed to Android. But I don't know much about iOS and don't have a ton of Apple gear. I have a developer account to deploy to the store, but would like to pass the apps to some friends with various devices to take a look at it before I deploy it to the store. These friends aren't local (as in, plugging in the devices).

What are my options with this? Can I create an ad-hoc certificate and send them the app to install or what do I do?

Any guides etc would be helpful. At this stage, I really don't want to go spending £1000 on Apple gear.

Answer (score 0):

Go for **[TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)**. Apple bought it and integrate with itune connect for Testing purpose. You have to create a provisioning profile to distribute your application with it and you have have internal test and even 1000 testers external with need of there UDID.

Answer (score 0):

You guess is right, create an Ad-Hoc profile, make sure your friends device UDID is linked in the profile and send it to him.

The other option is to use [iTunesConnect TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/), upload the app to [iTunesConnect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/) and release it a an internal beta. Register your friend as an technical member of you iTunesConnect account which will allow him to install the app use the TestFlight app from the App Store.

Last option is a public beta in TestFlight, for this option you do not need to register you friend as technical member of you iTunesConnect account. But you will have to send in your app for review with Apple. After review you can invited up to a 1000 beta test by mail.

The main advantage of the iTunesConnect Testflight it that you do not need the device UDID of your friends device. He can install the app on multiple device with the use of the same Apple ID that he registered for the invite.

Comment: thanks. when you say "send it to him" is that an email of the files and he double clicks them or something?

Comment: You will need to send the `ipa` to the tester, this he should then drop in iTunes on the application item and sync with his phone. The TestFlight option is the more easy one.